# Proof that two isomorphic types are different

Tags: coq

Given these two types,

```
Inductive unit : Set := tt.
Inductive otherUnit : Set := ttt.
```

Can Coq prove they are different, ie `unit <> otherUnit` ?

Both are singleton types in sort `Set` so it is not easy to find a `Set -> Prop` that differentiates them. For example, this does not even type check

```
Definition singletonTT (A : Set) : Prop := forall x : A, x = tt.
```

because `tt` has type `unit` instead of `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually admissible in Coq that these two types are equal; that is, you can neither prove they are equal or different, and it's consistent to assume either.

You can't express singletonTT in terms of `tt` because as you point out, it only type checks for the `unit` type. Instead you need to treat `A` opaquely; for example, you can express the property of being a singleton as `A /\ forall (x y:A), x = y`. Of course, both types are singletons so this doesn't distinguish them.

If you do assume `Axiom unit_otherUnit : unit = otherUnit`, then you can express something like `singletonTT` by casting `tt` to `otherUnit`: `eq_rec _ (fun S => S) tt otherUnit ax = ttt`.

When types have *different* cardinalities (which means they aren't isomorphic) you can use their cardinality to distinguish them and prove the types are distinct. Easy examples include False <> True and unit <> bool, and a more complicated example is `nat <> (nat -> nat)`.

Comment: Is is actually what I thought. But then if you set `Axiom ax : unit = otherUnit`, the equality `tt = ttt` still does not type check. Do you know why ?

Comment: The axiom is just an equality proof; `tt = ttt` still has syntactically different types, which `eq` does not allow. You can use `ax` to "cast" `tt` to be of type `otherUnit`; `Goal eq_rec _ (fun S => S) tt otherUnit ax = ttt`.

Comment: Great thanks. I think you should edit that into your answer.

Comment: Ok, I added it, although I think your question didn't really ask anything about what you wanted to do with the type equality.

Comment: My question didn't. But it's a great answer anyway :)